# Как создать базу данных из текстового файла?

Tags: c#, файлы

Делаю курсовую по созданию банкомата. По условиям пароли, имена и все данные хранятся в обычном текстовом файле. Нашёл на одном сайте такой пример, но не могу понять как теперь извлечь отсюда данные:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Определяем подключение
        OleDbConnection StrCon =
            new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Exp;Extended Properties=text");
        //Строка для выборки данных
        string  Select1 = "SELECT * FROM [Dictionary1.txt]";
        //Создание объекта Command
        OleDbCommand comand1 =new OleDbCommand(Select1, StrCon);
        //Определяем объект Adapter для взаимодействия с источником данных
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 =new OleDbDataAdapter(comand1);
        //Определяем объект DataSet
        DataSet AllTables =new DataSet();
        //Открываем подключение
        StrCon.Open();
        //Заполняем DataSet таблицей из источника данных
        adapter1.Fill(AllTables);
        //Заполняем обект datagridview для отображения данных на форме
        dataGridView1.DataSource = AllTables.Tables[0];
        StrCon.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Exp\Dictionary1.txt", false, Encoding.Default);
            //Добавление имен столбцов
            for(int j = 0; j<dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                sw.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText);
                if( j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1) 
                    sw.Write(",");
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
            for (int i= 0; i<dataGridView1.RowCount;i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j< dataGridView1.ColumnCount;j++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                    if (j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1) 
                        sw.Write(",");
                }
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: БД SQL Server? Кстати код Windows Forms полагаю неуместен потому что вопрос про БД.

Comment: А зачем вам база, если данные хранятся в текстовом файле?

Comment: Эх, куча столько удобных форматов... json, тот же xml. И парсить удобно.

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем случае я бы взял библиотеку [LINQ](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/), хоть она и весит как бронепоезд, но материала для курсовой зато много будет :-)
Данные можете хранить в текстовом файле но в формате XML, в LINQ есть парсер:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml"));
```

Затем можно вытворять такие вещи что профессор приумолкнет на минутку - например найти пароль пользователя vaska -

```
var vaska = (from c in xdoc.Descendants("users")
         where c.Element("username").Value() == "vaska"
         select c.Element("password").Value()).ToList();
```